# FileNotFound Exception while reading file from hdfs

Tags: file, hadoop

I am trying to read a file from HDFS using following code:

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/training/");

FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
String filePath = "hdfs" + "://" + "localhost:8020" + "/user/training/test.txt";

File fileToProcess = new File(filePath); // path of file
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToProcess);
```

The last statement of the program is returning following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
hdfs:/localhost:8020/user/training/test.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
```

Any idea what could be issue? File is present at the location.
Only difference that I could note is : Although I have put "//" in the URL, the last statement is omitting one slash while creating the input stream.

This code is being called from MR Driver class.

Comment: Was able to read using FSDataInputStream!

Answer (score 1):

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:8020"),
        configuration);
Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/training/test.txt");
System.out.println(fs.exists(path));
FSDataInputStream fin  = fs.open(path);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think I am missing something. It didn't work.

Comment: It is working fine with me. whats your error. otherwise you should add core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in configuration. conf.addResource(core-site.xml) and conf.addResource(hdfs-site.xml)

Comment: Sure. I will try and let you know.

Comment: haven't tried yet including resource files. I am getting following error. Not sure why one of the "/" gets omitted after "hdfs:"

    ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:training (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/localhost:8020/user/training/test.txt (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Tapan, 
Configuration Parameter fs.defaultFS must denotes only Namenode hostname .Why it has the value of the HDFS directory itself.Can you try removing it ?

Comment: Thanks. But I think I am missing something. It didn't work.